# MEF and Embedded Views in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mef

I have an MVC application that is using MEF for the controllers, all working fine.

http://bryanavery.co.uk/post/2012/03/12/Using-MEF-in-MVC-3.aspx

But I'm now wanting to take the next step and move my Views to be embedded in the DLL's and get MEF to inject the Views for MVC.

I have a collection of DLL's that will hold the different Views required for the application.

I'm using Razor, not that that should make much difference, anyone managed to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps you want to look at portable areas, here's a good write up
http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib/

here's mvccontrib
http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks I'm having a look at this now

Comment: Perfect, I also found a fully working sorce work at Membership starter kit  https://github.com/fretje/MembershipStarterKit

Answer (score 2):

[MvcCodeRouting](http://mvccoderouting.codeplex.com/) supports embedded views. Also, check out [this post](http://maxtoroq.github.io/2012/02/aspnet-mvc-plugins.html).